# Why does a Cronjob get suspended in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cronjob that used to spawn pods (that failed due to error). Now, I see the job getting suspended and a new job is created causing a scenario where there are 200 such jobs and none of them ever spawned a pod:

```
➜  ~ kubectl -n pc-control-plane get jobs -w
NAME              COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
canary-28091035   0/1                      16m
canary-28091040   0/1                      11m
canary-28091045   0/1                      6m34s
canary-28091050   0/1                      94s
canary-28091055   0/1                      0s
canary-28091055   0/1                      0s
```

I run this command and never get a pod pertaining to the job:

```
➜  ~ kubectl -n pc-control-plane get pods -w
```

There is another job that gets created and is also completed:

```
pg-migrator       1/1           5s         5s
```

But my job (which is a cronjob) never gets started. I tried deleting all the existing ones and then recreating my cluster but that did not help either.

When I manually edited the job for `suspend: false`, it spawned a pod. Issue is: how do I do this without manual intervention? Also, I never had to edit a job before and pods were spun up, they crashed a lot then though.

My cronjob definition is:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: canary
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: canary
            image: "{{ .Values.imageRegistry }}/canary:{{ .Values.version }}"
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: I think we would need to see the manifest for this CronJob before we could offer useful suggestions.

Comment: added, is that what you asked @larsks ?

Comment: Clusters I've worked with have run into trouble where the sheer quantity of failed Jobs has overloaded the cluster in some way.  If you have resource quotas configured this can also cause a similar symptom.